# Button touch event while sliding range only fires once

Tags: angularjs, html, ionic-framework

For an ionic framework app, I'd like to press a button while I'm sliding a range and am having trouble. While the range slider is moving or actively being touched, touching a button will fire the button's event only once. Further touches of the button appear to activate it (it depresses on screen), but it does not call the event function. The event handling is nothing fancy: the button uses on-touch for a function in my controller and the range input is bound using ng-model.

To reproduce:

- slide the range input
- while still holding and/or sliding the range input, touch the button. The buttonTouch() function is called on the the first button press. After that, buttonTouch() will not be called, and the button will appear as if it is being activated with each touch on screen.

I don't know that this can be tested in a browser, as it requires touching both controls at the same time (I used the Ionic View app).

example:

**html**

```
<ion-content class="padding" ng-controller="RangeCtrl">
  <button type="button" class="button button-large" on-touch="buttonTouch()">
    <i class="icon ion-pinpoint"></i>
  </button>

  <div class="padding">
    <canvas width="100" height="100" style="background: {{flipColor}};">
    </canvas>
  </div>

  <div class="range range-positive">
    <input type="range" ng-model="level">
    <span class="padding-left">{{level}}</span>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

**controller**

```
.controller('RangeCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.flip = false;
  $scope.flipColor = 'green'
  $scope.level = "50";

  $scope.buttonTouch = function() {
    $scope.flip = !$scope.flip;  

    $scope.flipColor = $scope.flip ? 'blue' : 'green';
  }
})
```

Comment: I didn't understand your problem very well. The buttonTouch() function is called only once when the button is pressed the first time and after that it appears to be disabled?

Comment: I'll edit and try to be more clear. While actively sliding the range input, touching the button will only call buttonTouch() once, instead of every time it is touched. The button will appear to press on the screen each subsequent time, but buttonTouch() will not be called.